# Why wont it let me commit my submodules?

Tags: git

So I recently did:

```
git submodule foreach git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

And I got a huge out put as it pulled and updated these submodules to the latest and greatest. I then did:

```
vagrant@vagrantpress:/vagrant/Freya-Vagrant$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   local-dev/content/mu-plugins/Freya-MU (modified content)
        modified:   local-dev/content/themes/freya-theme (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
vagrant@vagrantpress:/vagrant/Freya-Vagrant$ git commit -a
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   local-dev/content/mu-plugins/Freya-MU (modified content)
        modified:   local-dev/content/themes/freya-theme (modified content)

no changes added to commit
vagrant@vagrantpress:/vagrant/Freya-Vagrant$ git add -A
vagrant@vagrantpress:/vagrant/Freya-Vagrant$ git commit -a
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   local-dev/content/mu-plugins/Freya-MU (modified content)
        modified:   local-dev/content/themes/freya-theme (modified content)

no changes added to commit
vagrant@vagrantpress:/vagrant/Freya-Vagrant$
```

But as you can see it wont commit them because apparently there are no changes? I don't understand this. **What's really going on here?**

Comment: As a general comment, I personally think working with git submodules is not usually the best way to do things.  I don't know anything about wordpress in particular, but presumably there's some way to configure plugins/themes/whatever and have it manage the pulling in of these dependencies?   You might still want to reference local (individual) git projects for ease of development - don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the changes are in git submodule projects, rather than the root project.

Following the documentation at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules, you probably want to do something like:

```
cd local-dev/content/mu-plugins/Freya-MU
git checkout master # or some other branch
git submodule update --remote --merge

# make edits, e.g.:
vi README.md 
git commit -m "test" README.md

git submodule update --remote --rebase
git push --recurse-submodules=check  # follow the output from this command
```